# Does ellipses function in c must get an int argument before

Tags: c, printf, ellipse

According to what is written in the explanation in [C - Variable Arguments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm):

> Define a function with its last parameter as ellipses **and the one just before the ellipses is always an int** which will represent the number of arguments.

Is it really a must to send an int to the ellipse function before `...`?

I saw the prototype of the `printf()` function, and before `...` the function gets `const char *` and there isn't any `int` before the `...`.

Comment: It's not a "must" ... you are reading a tutorial about this option

Comment: I would not use tutorialspoint, at least a few years ago it was full of unclarities and mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

No, passing an `int` is not a REQUIREMENT, as proved by `printf()`.  What you see in the tutorial is specific to the `func()` and `average()` examples presented by the tutorial (although the `func()` example does not match the `int` explanation correctly, but the `average()` example does).

Only the caller knows how many parameter values it is passing in (and of what type(s)), so you need to design your variadic functions in such a way that the caller has to specify how many parameter values are actually being passed in (and optionally their types).  There are two ways to do that:

- passing in a required leading parameter.  This could be an `int` specifying the exact argument count.  Or it could be a string that the function parses to determine the arguments (this is what `printf` does).
- passing in a required sentry value as the last argument value.  Then the function simply uses all of the arguments it finds until it reaches that sentry.

Comment: If I recall correctly, although there does not need to be an int argument, there must be at least one argument before the ellipsis.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, because a `va_list` needs a named argument to determine where the optional variadic arguments begin in memory. If you want a function that can omit all arguments, you need an overload or macro that passes in a dummy argument to the real function.

Comment: Variadic parameters are not necessarily passed via memory. It depends on the ABI and modern ABI for CPUs suitable to use registers follow the normal conventions like for non-varioadic parameters. See AAPCS and - AFAIK - x64 ABIs for examples. Nothing of this is specified by the language standard, ther could be as well divine influence.

Comment: You could mention that in the answer. Although it states at least one argument should convey argument information to the callee, that alone does not rule out a declaration of `function(...)` where the callee already knows the first type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau,Eric Postpischil -
1. But we see that in printf function there isn't argument before the char*, although from reading your's correspondence it seems you say that at least one argument have to be send before the ellipses  so i am a little bit confuse . Can someone explain me please? 
2. The ellipse function uses va_arg(list,type), so if we will use a  required sentry value we still need to think of a way that the called function will know what are the types it need to ask each time she uses va_args?

Comment: @Eitanos30, in `printf`, the `char*` IS the one fixed argument before the ellipse. Look at the declaration for yourself: `​int printf( const char *format, ... );` The `format` parameter is *always required*, but anything after it is *optional*, depending on the particular content of the `format` string, which provides `printf` with all of the information it needs to know the ellipse argument count and types.  There is no sentry used.

Comment: @Eitanos30 If you use a sentry to end the argument list, all of the ellipse argument types must follow a pre-determined pattern of some kind that both caller and callee agree on, so the callee can use `va_arg()` with the correct type for each ellipse argument. For instance, making every ellipse argument the same type. Or having the value of one ellipse argument determine the type of the next ellipse argument. Or, having each ellipse argument be a struct that contains a type field and a union of allowed value types to pick from.

Comment: @RemyLebeau before using va_args, we must create va_list by va_start macro. va_start gets two parameters: one is va_list and the second one seems to be the number of arguments send by ellipses.
If i will use a sentry value, as i understand (please correct me if i'm wrong), it won't help me know how many arguments are passed by ellipses since sentry value is one of those arguments, and access to it is only available via va_args (after va_start macros was written).
What i'm trying to ask/understand is, if sentry value is part of the ellipses argument or part of the arguments that come before..

Comment: @Eitanos30 "*va_start gets two parameters: one is va_list and the second one seems to be the number of arguments send by ellipses*" - WRONG, the 2nd parameter is the **name** of the last fixed parameter before the ellipse, to let the `va_list` know where to begin getting values from. The variadic function being called doesn't know how many values are being passed in the ellipse, so it can't pass a count to `va_start()` even if it wanted to. If you use a sentry value to signal the end of the ellipse, you have to loop through the `va_list` until you read the sentry value from `va_arg()`.